# Add Spring Actuator's healthcheck without Boot and @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I want to add Actuator to my Spring application (not a Spring Boot).
To be precise, I need to use actuators HealthCheck, so I'll be able to create beans of different health indicators and they would create complete healthcheck on /health.

At first I tried to add `@EndpointAutoConfiguration` to my `@Configuration` class, but there is beans conflicts, because I have my customs beans, that I really need, so there's no need in other Configurations other then `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Hey, did you get an answer to this problem? I have the same issue right now where I do not want to use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication` but want to use actuators.

Comment: @Sujan not really, I’ve created custom HealthIndicator and HealthIndicatorCollector. At /healthcheck request HealthcheckCollector gets all HealthIdicator beans from context and gives me their statuses. And with that I’ve added “critical” field for every HeathIndicator, so HeathCollector can give me health of my service ignoring indicators that are not critical but might be useful for monitoring.

Comment: @ottercoder Could you please share us the piece of custom code your have used here.

Comment: @BandhamManikanta found some code from 2016 :D

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution can be creating custom HealthIndicator and HealthIndicatorCollector with critical fields. Also adding a servlet:

```
contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(platformHealthCheckServlet), "/healthcheck");
```

That collects all the custom HealthIndicators from context and creating nice status json at /healthcheck endpoint:

```
@Autowired
public CustomHealthCheckServlet(Map<String, CustomHealthIndicator> healthIndicatorMap, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.healthIndicatorMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(healthIndicatorMap);
    this.mapper = objectMapper;
}
```

*CustomHealthIndicator*, which adds *setCritical* method:

```
public interface CustomHealthIndicator extends HealthIndicator {
    void setCritical(boolean var1);
}
```

*CustomAbstractHealthIndicator* which overrides *doHealthCheck* method in *AbstractHealthIndicator* adding critical detail to its builder and creating its own abstract method *doCheck*:

```
public abstract class CustomAbstractHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator 
implements CustomHealthIndicator {
    private boolean critical = false;

    public CustomAbstractHealthIndicator() {
     }

    public void setCritical(boolean critical) {
        this.critical = critical;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.withDetail("critical", this.critical);
        this.doCheck(builder);
    }

    protected abstract Builder doCheck(Builder var1) throws Exception;
}
```

And there's another Custom class that aggregates health beans with calculating status for the whole application based on a critical status of every health, ignoring indicators that are not critical but might be useful for monitoring:

```
public class CustomHealthAggregator implements HealthAggregator {

    private List<String> statusOrder;

    public CustomHealthAggregator() {
        setStatusOrder(Status.DOWN, Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE, Status.UP, 
Status.UNKNOWN);
    }

    public void setStatusOrder(Status... statusOrder) {
        String[] order = new String[statusOrder.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < statusOrder.length; i++) {
            order[i] = statusOrder[i].getCode();
         }
    setStatusOrder(Arrays.asList(order));
    }

    public void setStatusOrder(List<String> statusOrder) {
        Assert.notNull(statusOrder, "StatusOrder must not be null");
        this.statusOrder = statusOrder;
    }

    protected Status aggregateStatus(List<Status> candidates) {
        // Only sort those status instances that we know about
        List<Status> filteredCandidates = new ArrayList<Status>();
        for (Status candidate : candidates) {
            if (this.statusOrder.contains(candidate.getCode())) {
                filteredCandidates.add(candidate);
            }
        }
        // If no status is given return UP
        if (filteredCandidates.isEmpty()) {
            return Status.UP;
        }
        // Sort given Status instances by configured order
        Collections.sort(filteredCandidates, 
        new StatusComparator(this.statusOrder));
        return filteredCandidates.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Health aggregate(Map<String, Health> healths) {
        List<Status> statusCandidates = healths.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(healthEntry -> 
              healthEntry.getValue().getDetails().get("critical").equals(true))
                .map(e -> e.getValue().getStatus())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Status status = aggregateStatus(statusCandidates);
        Map<String, Object> details = new LinkedMap();
        details.put("version", AppVersionUtil.getAppVersion());
        details.putAll(aggregateDetails(healths));
        return new Health.Builder(status, details).build();
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> aggregateDetails(Map<String, Health> healths) 
    {
        return new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(healths);
    }

    private class StatusComparator implements Comparator<Status> {

        private final List<String> statusOrder;

        StatusComparator(List<String> statusOrder) {
            this.statusOrder = statusOrder;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Status s1, Status s2) {
            int i1 = this.statusOrder.indexOf(s1.getCode());
            int i2 = this.statusOrder.indexOf(s2.getCode());
            return (i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i1 == i2 ? s1.getCode().compareTo(s2.getCode()) : 1));
        }

    }
}
```